# Stored Procedure in mySQL workbench (INSERT INTO error)

Tags: mysql, sql, insert-into

I'm running into an error in my stored procedure, and after numerous YT videos and forums, I still have no clue where I'm going wrong. Given what I'm trying to do, it all seems to look correct.

Here's the deal. I take in some information to buy some stock, I use an `IF` to make sure that I have enough money to make the purchase, I then insert the purchase information into my `TRADES` table and update the cash balance in `ACCOUNTS` to reflect the spending of $$.

I can't even test to see if it works correctly because it won't run. The only error I'm getting is at `INSERT INTO`, in which it says `error: INTO (into) is not valid input at this position`

I have done ALL of my insert statements the exact same way, and have no idea why this particular syntax is incorrect? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Below are two approaches, both with errors.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `BUY` (TID INT,ID INT, CASH INT, T_NAME VARCHAR(4) , 
TCOUNT INT, TBUYDATE DATE, TBUYPRICE INT  )

BEGIN

IF (ACCOUNT.CASH_BALANCE >= (TCOUNT * TBUYPRICE), 

INSERT INTO TRADES (TRADE_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, TRADE_NAME, TRADE_COUNT, TRADE_BUYDATE, TRADE_BUYPRICE) 

VALUES (TID, ID, T_NAME, TCOUNT, TBUYDATE, TBUYPRICE) 

AND UPDATE ACCOUNT.CASH_BALANCE  

WHERE ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID = ID
SET ACCOUNT.CASH_BALANCE = (ACCOUNT.CASH_BALANCE - (TCOUNT * TBUYPRICE)),

NULL

)




END
```

I have also tried the following, however I get an error on END  `missing subclause or other elements before end`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `BUY` (TID INT,ID INT, CASH INT, T_NAME VARCHAR(4) , TCOUNT 
INT, TBUYDATE DATE, TBUYPRICE INT  )

BEGIN

IF (ACCOUNT.CASH_BALANCE >= (TCOUNT * TBUYPRICE))

THEN 
INSERT INTO TRADES (TRADE_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, TRADE_NAME, TRADE_COUNT, 
TRADE_BUYDATE, TRADE_BUYPRICE) 
VALUES (TID, ID, T_NAME, TCOUNT, TBUYDATE, TBUYPRICE);
UPDATE ACCOUNT.CASH_BALANCE  
SET ACCOUNT.CASH_BALANCE = (ACCOUNT.CASH_BALANCE - (TCOUNT * TBUYPRICE))
WHERE ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_ID = ID;

ELSE #noinsert


END
```

Comment: I should also add, I'm not entirely sure that `NULL` is a good idea, but I want it to do nothing if the cash_balance is not enough to make the purchase. I see no problem with it, but perhaps there's a smarter way of ending it.

Comment: I would reformat this to use IF/THEN/ELSE as opposed to the IF function. I would highly recommend including a `BEGIN...END` block as well. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html

Comment: Also I think you are missing a right parenthesis after `TBUYPRICE))`

Comment: Apologize, I do have the begin and end, just left those out :) Figured they were assumed!

Comment: @JacobH I'm pretty sure it's correct. If I insert a right paren after it ends the IF statement early.  Also, I don't know that IF ELSE THEN works on mySql workbench. I tried using it and it wasn't recognizing it. Do you have a link for how it's done? I'll look around.
After looking around, im almost positive this is the only IF statement syntax for mySQL. It's all I can find.

Comment: Update set where.  Not update where set.

Comment: @Twelfth, fixed the issue for the second piece of code, however a new error occurs. It now erroring END. I have updated my post to reflect this code and error.

Comment: The IF ACCOUNT.CASH_BALANCE is wrong, you may need an IF (SELECT 1 FROM account WHERE CASH_BALANCE >= (TCOUNT * TBUYPRICE)). There are multiple strange errors inside, to really help you, the defintion of the tables account and trades is needed.

Comment: This isn't valid : ELSE #noinsert    what are you trying to do there?  Else no action, just delete the line

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors/corrections:

- The Delimiter command was not used, so he gets confused on the end of statement and the end of the procedure definition
- The account table needs to be selected in an exists statement
- I've used a local variable l_cash instead of repeating TCOUNT * TBUYPRICE (Not an error).
- The ELSE statement was not necessary and an END IF; was missing.
- Update statement corrected.

Here is the corrected code:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `BUY` (TID INT,ID INT, CASH INT, T_NAME VARCHAR(4) , TCOUNT 
INT, TBUYDATE DATE, TBUYPRICE INT)

BEGIN
DECLARE l_cash INT DEFAULT 0;
SET l_cash = TCOUNT * TBUYPRICE;

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Account WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = ID AND CASH_BALANCE >= l_cash) THEN 

INSERT INTO TRADES (TRADE_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, TRADE_NAME, TRADE_COUNT, 
TRADE_BUYDATE, TRADE_BUYPRICE) 
VALUES (TID, ID, T_NAME, TCOUNT, TBUYDATE, TBUYPRICE);

UPDATE ACCOUNT 
SET CASH_BALANCE = (CASH_BALANCE - l_cash)
WHERE ACCOUNT_ID = ID;

END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```